# Slack Block Kit Font

Tags: slack

for Slack Block Kit, I understand it uses JSON and different keys to style the message.

Does anyone know if the font can be changed for the Block Kit? I've seen instances where this has been done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some very basic styling of your message if you use `"type": "mrkdwn"` (not plain_text) for your text elements.

More info here: https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting